# Audio Problem in Video recording using Wowza SDK MP4Writer in iOS

Tags: android, ios, wowza, video-recording, wowza-transcoder

I am facing an issue when I captured a video stream using Wowza SDK MP4Writer. Here's [the link](https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/gocoder-sdk-samples-ios/blob/master/SDKSampleApp/MP4Writer.h) 
I am save recording stream as mp4 format in iOS and upload on S3 bucket. When I am trying to play save mp4 video stream on android media player then its audio is muted. Although same video is playing fine on iOS (No audio muted issue).

I have changed the CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef class but no success.

```
(CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef) makeAudioFormatDescription {

    CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef audioFormat = nil;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription absd = {0};
    absd.mSampleRate = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] sampleRate];
    absd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    absd.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;

    CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(NULL, &absd, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &audioFormat);

    return audioFormat;
}
```

Video should play fine on both platforms (iOS & Android).

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what version of the SDK you are using? Also, please share what Android devices you are testing on. The Wowza SDK is not audio codec compatible with certain devices and that results in the video working without sound.

Comment: We are using Wowza SDK Version 1.7.0.1079. We are testing on Samsung S9+, Samsung S10+, Google Pixel 2,Google Pixel 3XL,Samsung S7Edge.